# How to add a contextmenustrip to richtextbox control in the designer?

Tags: winforms

I want that the user will be able in runtime to make right mouse click button inside the richtextbox and then paste inside any text. for now I can only make ctrl + v but I want also to add the contextmenustrip option.

the problem is that in the designer in the richtextbox properties window when I click on drop down arrow of the ContextMenuStrip the only option is none there is no option to create/add a new contextmenustrip.

[image: richtextbox contextmenustrip]

Comment: Well, add a ContextMenuStrip to the Form, then you'll find it in the dropdown